# ASP.net: problem ignored date after insert?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, date, calendar

I have a problem inserting the date in the database. When inserted, the value of TextDate is ignored and 1990-01-01 (default date) is inserted, which means the date is null

code :

```
<asp:Label ID="Label11" align="right" runat="server" Text=" Date" class=" col-md-3 col-sm-12 test "></asp:Label>
                      <asp:TextBox ID="TextDate" runat="server" align="right" ReadOnly="true" Class=" form-control col-md-6 col-sm-6 dd test" BackColor="White" ></asp:TextBox>
                      <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="Calendar1" PopupButtonID="imgPopup" runat="server" TargetControlID="TextDate" Format="dd-MM-yyyy" > </cc1:CalendarExtender> 
 
 and C# 


 myPara.Add("@decisionyear", Convert.ToDateTime(TextDate.Text)); // date
```

[image: when select date]

[image: after inserting]

Comment: Did you debug the code and check what value you are getting in `(TextDate.Text)`?

Comment: Possible to attach your data insertion SqlCommand and database table schema in the question.